# How to parse this date format in Java

Tags: java, date-formatting

I have this format:

```
2011-10-10T01:45:20+00:00
```

I tried using `LocalDateTime.parse("2011-10-10T01:45:20+00:00")`

but I got error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseEception: Text '2011-10-10T01:45:20+00:00' could not be parse, unparsed text found
```

Answer (score 3):

The default formatter is `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME : '2011-12-03T10:15:30'`, the offset is not in,

You may parse using `OffsetDateTime` class that uses `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME : '2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00'` as formatter

```
OffsetDateTime.parse("2011-10-10T01:45:20+00:00") // print 2011-10-10T01:45:20Z
```

---

You can still use `LocalDateTime` but you need to specify the formatter

```
LocalDateTime.parse("2011-10-10T01:45:20+00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME); // 2011-10-10T01:45:20
```

---

> [`Oracle Documentation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#predefined)

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2011-10-10T01:45:20+00:00" )
```

## Wrong class

The [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class is not appropriate to your input. That class represents only a date and a time-of-day but without any [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone), so it does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline.

Your input string in contrast represents a moment, with an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds: `+00:00`

## `OffsetDateTime`

Correct class for your input is [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

Your input string is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. These standard formats are used by default in the *java.time* classes. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2011-10-10T01:45:20+00:00" ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/yxvC68).

> odt.toString(): 2011-10-10T01:45:20Z

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

FYI, the difference between offset and zone:

- An offset-from-UTC is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds. Nothing more. Represented by [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) class.
- A time zone is *much* more. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. A time zone carries a name in `Continent/Region` format such as `America/Montreal` or `Africa/Tunis`. Represented by [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) class.

Comment: `Modern` refers to `since Java 1.8`, yes?

Comment: @second If you mean does this require Java 8, yes, the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310 appear in Java 8 and later, with a back-port to Java 6 and Java 7 available in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.  But, no, my use of "modern" here refers to the elegant design of the library using lessons learned from its predecessor, the *Joda-Time* project, and the anti-lessons learned from the terrible legacy classes. One example: *java.time* is entirely read-only, using immutable objects, as is appropriate to this kind of value-oriented content.

Comment: @BasilBourque how can I get the string format out of the OfsetDateTime? (I want it in the same format as this 2011-10-10T01:45:20+00:00

Comment: @JackThomson Do you understand that the `Z` on the end means `+00:00`? Pronounced “Zulu”, it is a common shortcut for an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds, and is officially defined in the ISO 8601 standard. If you insist on the `+00:00`, use the `DateTimeFormatter` class to generate a string. This has been covered many many times already, so I'll not cover it here. Search Stack Overflow, and study the formatting pattern codes in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

You could provide ISO date formatter in the parse method like this

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

LocalDate.parse("2011-10-10T01:45:20+00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
```